# Get time in milliseconds to profile a function duration

Tags: c++, profiling

I have a function that writes a file. I need to profile the function in with two parameters, so I can see the difference. (Do not tell me about Visual Studios Profiling tools, I want to do it by myself). I want to apply something like this:

```
double start = getTime();
myFunction("param1");
double request = getTime() - start;
printf_s("Request time: %f", request);
```

How can I do this? (what have above is just pseudo-code, I don't know the real functions names)

Comment: [Look no further than the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). The example on the main page actually does exactly what you want.

Comment: A more specific library example. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point

Comment: This has been asked so many times, have you searched before asking?

Answer (score 24):

Use `std::chrono`, here is an example that will work for your code:

```
#include <chrono>
int main()
{
    using milli = std::chrono::milliseconds;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    myFunction("param1");
    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "myFunction() took "
              << std::chrono::duration_cast<milli>(finish - start).count()
              << " milliseconds\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use either:

1. a [std::clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) variable and divide it by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` in order to obtain the seconds (needs `#include <ctime>`)
2. for `WinAPI` you can use [GetTickCount()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and divide it by 1000 in order to obtain the seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Though It's pretty late But I would answer the question :
One can use getTickCount() function of c++.
The basic syntax will be somewhat like :

```
double start=(double)getTickCount();
//Your code
.
.
.
start= ((double)getTickCount() - start)/getTickFrequency(); 
cout<<"time spent in executing the code ="<<start;
```

Comment: It is notable to say that this only works for Windows. For Linux, you'd need to use something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows API functions:

QueryPerformanceCounter

QueryPerformanceFrequency

see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

C++11 provides the [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) namespace, wich has a set of standard time-date functions and types. Note that the example of that reference page does exactly what you are trying to do.

I recommend you [this Bo Quian's youtube tutorial](http://youtu.be/M13otPgOePs) about `std::chrono`.